# How can I correct a word on the CKEditor field?

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

When editing a text area in Drupal 8, right clicking a highlighted spelling error doesn't produce a context menu option to correct the misspelled word. How can I correct the word on the CKEditor field?

[image: Misspelled Word Example]

Comment: Did you install a CKEditor spell checker plugin? [By default CKeditor in D8 does not provide spell checking](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vLv1T.jpg)

Comment: NVM I'm still using 8.0.5 in my dev, the [The spell checking feature was added in 8.1.0](https://www.drupal.org/node/2624982)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to AdamPS in [Enable browsers' (native) spell checker in CKEditor](https://www.drupal.org/node/2307141#comment-10122036)

> 2) **If you browser supports spelling suggestions, the way to access
>   them in Drupal is slightly different**. When you are in an edit area,
>   then the normal browser context menu may be replaced by the editing
>   context menu. However you can access the browser menu **by clicking
>   Control**. [But on a Mac it is potentially command and on a tablet
>   ....??]

You need to hold down CTRL before right clicking. (which worked for me on Windows OS)

---

An alternative would be to install the [SpellCheckAsYouType(SCAYT)](http://ckeditor.com/addon/scayt) plugin for CKEDITOR

[image]

> **Note:** You have to build a custom module to install CKeditor plugins in
>   D8.

Comment: It looks like it's Alt+Cmd (⌥+⌘) for Mac OSX.